# Using copulas to sample a probability distribution

Tags: joint-distribution, marginal-distribution, copula

Say I have two random variables, X and Y. Their joint probability density function is a uniform distribution inside the triangle with vertices at (0,0), (0,1) and (1,2). The area is 1 so the joint pdf is 1. Calculating the marginal cumulative distribution function I get P_X = x^2 and P_Y = y - (y/2)^2. The question is how do I hook up two random number generators U(0,1) and V(0,1) to generate a sample of points distributed according to the above by using copula theory? Note that we have the full information and do not need to assume anything about the relationship of the marginals. I have inverted the cdfs but the problem is that the marginals do not encode the triangular restriction so some of the points generated will fall outside the specified triangle. Thanks very much for any help.